# In Scala, how to define a implicit value/parameter in companion object?

Tags: scala, session, implicit

I saw codes below from this [Link](https://github.com/gnufied/scala-query/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/novocode/squery/session/SessionFactory.scala)

```
abstract class SessionFactory {

  protected[squery] def createConnection(): Connection

  def createSession(): Session = new Session(this)

  def withSession[T](f: Session => T): T = {
    val s = createSession()
    try { f(s) } finally s.close()
  }

  def withSession[T](f: => T): T =
    withSession { s: Session => SessionFactory.dyn.withValue(s)(f) }
}

object SessionFactory {

  private val dyn = new DynamicVariable[Session](null)

  implicit def getThreadSession: Session = {
    val s = dyn.value
    if(s eq null)
      throw new SQLException("No implicit thread session available; getThreadSession() can only be used within a withSession block")
    else s
  }
}
```

I don't know how could `def withSession[T](f: => T): T` get the value for `s:Session`, so I tried to reproduce this usage of `implicit` in a simple snippet:

```
class printTest {
  def printWithParameter(s:String) = println(s)
  def printWithImplicit = printWithParameter(s:String)
}

object printTest {
  implicit val sp:String = "implicit value"
  implicit def getString:String = "implicit def"
}

val pt = new printTest()
pt.printWithImplicit
```

But the `printTest` doesn't work, the compiler says:

```
Error:(3, 47) not found: value s
  def printWithImplicit = printWithParameter(s:String)
                                             ^
```

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have been misled. The implicit is not being used, because that method is *not* getting a value for `Session`. Let's review it:

```
def withSession[T](f: => T): T =
  withSession { s: Session => SessionFactory.dyn.withValue(s)(f) }
```

So, it takes an `f` of type `T`, passed by-name (that is, it is evaluated when used, not when `withSession` is called). It then calls `withSession` *passing a function from `Session` to `T`*. It does *not* create a `Session`, it *asks* for a `Session`, so to speak. So let's see what it called:

```
def withSession[T](f: Session => T): T = {
  val s = createSession()
  try { f(s) } finally s.close()
}
```

Here it takes a function from `Session` to `T` (which is going to be `s: Session => SessionFactory.dyn.withValue(s)(f)`), *creates* a `Session`, and then use that session to invoke the function that was passed. The session creation is just a `new Session(this)`, so nowhere is there any implicit being used.

Answer (score 2):

This reason you get

```
Error:(3, 47) not found: value s
  def printWithImplicit = printWithParameter(s:String)
                                             ^
```

is because you defined a function called `printWithImplicit` which takes no parameter and return `Unit`. It can be explicitly written as: `def printWithImplicit(): Unit`

Since it takes no parameters, so its function body, in this case, `printWithParameter(s:String)`, find no definition of `s`

Back to your question.

You need to `import printTest.sp` before

```
val pt = new printTest()
pt.printWithImplicit
```

I stripped your example down a bit:

```
class printTest {
  def printWithParameter(s:String) = println(s)
  def printWithImplicit(implicit s:String) = printWithParameter(s)
}

object printTest {
  implicit val sp:String = "implicit value"
}

import printTest.sp
val pt = new printTest()
pt.printWithImplicit
```